# Why is there xmlns in my html output

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

In the html output file from an XSLT process (using saxon9he), there have been 155 occurrences of *xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"* inserted into a variety of tr elements

The part of xsl that uses xpath-functions is

```
<xsl:if test="(string(@hideIfHardwareIs)='') or (not(fn:matches(string($input_doc//inf[@id='5'), string(@hideIfHardwareIs), 'i')))">
```

unless I am reading it wrong, matches takes 3 arguments, a string, another string and then a flag in which case this is case-insensitive.

What I don't undestand is that the tr elements that are showing up with the xmlns arent close to the portion or xsl that the matches() function is done at.

The XSL file I am working with is 2100 lines and the XML file it parses is 12800 lines. So I don't think I can share it easily. I've inherited this and need to (at this time) maintain it.

What are somethings i can look for within the XSL that would insert the xmlns into the html output?

Comment: Oh, I might have figured it out.
Any elements created outside of xsl seem to have this xmlns inserted into them. I'm checking and will comment back if that is true. Unless of course someone else knows that this is why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those functions do not need to be prefixed.

Remove the `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` from your `xsl:stylesheet` and remove the `fn:` prefix from the xpath functions.

Examples:

**XML Input**

```
<foo>test</foo>
```

**XSLT 2.0 #1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="fn:matches(.,'^t')">
            <bar><xsl:value-of select="."/></bar>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<bar xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">test</bar>
```

**XSLT 2.0 #2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="matches(.,'^t')">
            <bar><xsl:value-of select="."/></bar>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<bar>test</bar>
```

Comment: Correct answer. Some IDE's insert this namespace declaration at the start of every stylesheet. It's quite unnecessary. If you do want to include it (because for some reason you prefer to write fn:position() rather than position()), you should include it in the exclude-result-prefixes attribute so it doesn't find its way into the output.